# Finding OS build version in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know you can get the navigator.appVersion and navigator.platform values in the browser. But can I get more fine grained version than that? For example in Mac you can get the build version from the about menu. Is it possible to get that somehow in JS code?

Comment: Get the browser version. The user agent string is the closest you can get.

Comment: Do you mean the build version of the browser, or of the operating system?

Comment: Not of the browser, I am looking for the OS build version.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson - That is what I suspected too but just wanted to check with SO to be sure.

Comment: @R11 then you're question might be closed as opinion based then. I think that's the only way.